# GeoAlchemy2: Get the lat, lon of a point

Tags: gis, postgis, wkt, geoalchemy2, wkb

Consider the following [`SQLAalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) / [`GeoAlchemy2`](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.6/index.html) ORM with a geometry field:

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry, WKTElement

class Item(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    geom = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINTZ', srid=4326))
```

When I update an item in the PostgreSQL shell:

```
UPDATE item SET geom = st_geomFromText('POINT(2 3 0)', 4326) WHERE id = 5;
```

Fetching the field:

```
items = session.query(Item).\
    filter(Item.id == 3)

for item in items:
    print item.geom
```

Gives:

```
01e9030000000000000000004000000000000008400000000000000000
```

This isn't a proper WKB - at least, it does not parse with [Shapely's `loads`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).

**How do I get the `lat`/`lon` of the `geom` field?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fetching the `lat`, `lon` via [ST_X](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [ST_Y](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Y.html) might not be the most elegant approach, but it works:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

items = session.query(
            Item, 
            func.st_y(Item.geom), 
            func.st_x(Item.geom)
        ).filter(Item.id == 3)

for item in items:
    print(item.geom)
```

Gives:

```py
(<Item 3>, 3.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: How do I do it without access to the session?  I'm trying to add lat & lng properties to my point model for easy access.

Answer (score 6):

geoalchemy2 [to_shape](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/geoalchemy2/shape.html?highlight=to_shape) function to convert a :class:`geoalchemy2.types.SpatialElement`
to a Shapely geometry.

in Item class :

```py
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape

point = to_shape(self.geo)

return {
    'latitude': point.y,
    'longitude': point.x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Point type syntax is

```
Point ( Lat, Long)
```

So basic from **mosi_kha's answer**, return should be

```
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape

point = to_shape(self.geo)

return {
    'latitude': point.x,
    'longitude': point.y
}
```